# Can I have a cup of water to clean my teeth and to wash down my food after eating, without a Bracha?

Tags: blessing, food

Is this like using water to take a pill or is this considered drinking the water?

Comment: Did you mean to put a comma after "eating"? The current title is ambiguous

Comment: Are you not thirsty after a meal? If so, then you will be enjoying it so this is pertinent to the question (otherwise, if you are not thirsty, I assume you've already made a shehakol on some other drink?)